# Резервное копирование файлов на сервере

Tags: php

Мне нужно зарезервировать сайт (файлы не базу), нужно что то бесплатное, что бы создало архив и отправило на почту либо позволило скачать. Возможно это будет какой-то скрипт который можно залить через FTP. Ранее я встречал такое, а как понадобилась не могу найти.

Comment: У гугла сегодня выходной?

Comment: Зависит от условий. Если сервер полноценный — unison, duplicati, bacula. Сделает инкрементальный бэкап, сожмет, пошифрует, положит куда надо. Если сервер менее полноценный — опишите, что на нем есть. Один PHP и FTP-доступ для заливки скриптов? В Google на «php backup files» находятся несколько решений, например [это](http://campstamba.com/2010/12/create-your-own-php-backup-solution-complete-tutorial-with-source-files/) (см. «Server Files Backup»). Но, возможно, проще делать бэкап не на сайте, а снаружи его, настроив хоть на домашнем компьютере задачу «слить все новое по FTP и запаковать»?

Answer (score 1):

Пакуйте все в архив и отправьте в письме и на случай, если почта клиента блокирует аттачи, дайте в письме ссылку для скачки архива. А в php есть классы для архивации. Поищите.